# How to use a matrix as an argument for a function in c?

Tags: arrays, c, function, matrix, arguments

I'm trying to use the C code below to generate a matrix based on a given formula, but not being able to pass the array as an argument to the function that generates it, because the compiler output  errors that say something about incompatible types. But why? I've created an int array, so why it says that an array of int passed as an int value is wrong? How can I correctly pass the matrix as an argument to the function?

Here is the code that i have implemented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int imprimeMatriz (int*, int, int);
int main(){
    int m,n;
    printf("Entre com linhas e colunas da matriz");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    int  matrix[m][n];
    imprimeMatriz(matrix,m,n);
     for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<n;j++){
    printf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int imprimeMatriz(int p, int m, int n){

    for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<n;j++){
    p = (5-i)*(j+1);
    }
        }

   return p;
}
```

And those are the errors that I get when trying to compile with `cc -o matrix matrix.c`

```
matrix.c: In function ‘main’:
matrix.c:10:19: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘imprimeMatriz’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   10 |     imprimeMatriz(matrix,m,n);
      |                   ^~~~~~
      |                   |
      |                   int (*)[n]
matrix.c:4:20: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[n]’
    4 | int imprimeMatriz (int*, int, int);
      |                    ^~~~
matrix.c: At top level:
matrix.c:19:5: error: conflicting types for ‘imprimeMatriz’; have ‘int(int,  int,  int)’
   19 | int imprimeMatriz(int p, int m, int n){
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
matrix.c:4:5: note: previous declaration of ‘imprimeMatriz’ with type ‘int(int *, int,  int)’
    4 | int imprimeMatriz (int*, int, int);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also have tried solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425083/matrix-as-argument-to-a-function-in-c) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644918/how-to-use-a-pointer-to-a-matrix-as-an-argument-in-a-function-in-c), but without success

Comment: Please post the error messages as text, not as an image. You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: The posts you linked *are* the solution, so show your attempt at implementing them.

Comment: Try declaring `imprimeMatrix` as `void imprimeMatrix(int m, int n, int p[m][n])` and fixing up the code accordingly.

Comment: Your variable `matrix` is an array *of arrays* of `int` values. The argument `p` is a pointer to a single `int` value.

Comment: `i<n` should be `i<m`. `printf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);` should be `printf("%d",matrix[i][j]);` (perhaps you should print some spaces and newlines too). But those are the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way is to use pointers to array.

Example:

```
void initMatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*matrix)[cols])
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        for(size_t col; col < cols; col++)
            matrix[row][col] = rand();
}
```

Comment: ITYM `row < rows`.

Comment: @IanAbbott indeed

Answer (score 0):

Thing is that you cant pass arrays like that in a function.
but you can pass every single elements from your matrix into your function like in exemple1 or if you really want to pass the entire array, you can pass it as a pointer. It's a little bit more complicated but it's in exemple 2.

[Exemple1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk1UI.png)    [Exemple2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu8LN.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots (or links to screenshots) of code. Include the text of the code in the answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).